# Is it possible that the same VISA debit card numbers could be issued to different people by different banks?

Tags: credit-card, banks, financial

I'm wondering if is it possible that the same VISA debit card numbers could ever be issued to different people by different banks or companies?

Comment: this probably isn't dreadfully on topic for this site, however the answer is no.  Each issuer has what's known as a BIN number which is the first six digits of the 15/16 digit card number.  That BIN is unique to that bank/company, so no other company can use it to issue a card.  As such there wouldn't be a circumstance where there's an overlap.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about banking, not security.

Answer (score 1):

[edited]

whilst a card issuer may choose to reuse PAN (long number) to identity a card, a  PAN cannot normally be reissued by a different card issuer. The reason for this is because the BIN (first 6 digits) is issued uniquely to a card issuer.

There is one exception:  If card issuer is bought by another card issuer (e.g. bank 1 buys bank 2) then card number may be reissued under the new name of the card issuing organisation - but really this is an edge condition and in the spirit of the question the answer is largely no

Note:  In the UK, Clydesdale reissued mastercard PANs, but eventually stopped after obvious problems occurred.  see: http://www.theguardian.com/money/2003/may/10/creditcards.debt1

Comment: That is a different scenario that the one the question is about, which is the issuance of a single card number by *different* banks.